# Visualizing Character Strings in Different Colors with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a better visualization than the one you can see in the image:

[image]

Currently, this is a HTML page with spans as rectangles. Of course I got follow this way to get a more dynamic presentation of the data. But I'm curious, if this can be done with D3.js in a better way.

Is there a chart/visualization type that can be used to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest you look through the d3 documentation and examples as there are many, many different kinds of visualisation possible. d3 gives you a handy way to bind data to DOM elements and dynamically update your visualisation as the data change. Someone has probably created a display like this somewhere out on the great wide interwebz.

Comment: For me i thing you must build it manualy, by using bar chart ract type, D3 can achieve that chart, the problem is, more complex the chart require deep understand of  D3 it self, cos D3 build function only can make basic chart for custum it you must get down to it, take a look of candle chart in stock exchange,that is axample, for your chart is http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084